# My friends can't connect to my Minecraft Hamachi server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My internet provider doesn't lets me to open ports unless I buy a static IP. So I researched a bit and learned that I can use Hamachi to open a server to play with my friends without opening ports. I downloaded and sucsessfully set up minecraft server files. When I double click the `server.jar` file, a GUI pops up and starts the server. Later I installed Hamachi and created a new network. According to the tutorial video, I copied the Hamachi's ipv4 adress and pasted inside `server.properties` file. But now when I double click the `server.jar` file, a GUI pops up and instantly closes.

To see the error message, I runned the `server.jar` file from command prompt and saw below output:

```
[18:25:44] [main/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[18:25:44] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[18:25:44] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[18:25:44] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[18:25:44] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[18:25:44] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[18:25:44] [main/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[18:25:44] [Worker-Main-13/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[18:25:45] [Worker-Main-13/INFO]: Loaded 1137 advancements
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.17.1
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on 25.51.131.200:25565
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[18:25:46] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[18:25:46] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
[18:25:46] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[18:25:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[18:25:46] [Server thread/ERROR]: Exception stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "abr.o_()" because "Γÿâ" is null
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:588) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.u(SourceFile:624) ~[server.jar:?]
        at aas.u(SourceFile:585) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(SourceFile:734) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:270) ~[server.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

When I remove the IP adress from `server.properties` file and run the `server.jar` file, as I said a GUI pops up and starts the server. As a result I can join to my server by typing `localhost`; but as it's *local* my friends who are from another country can't join to my server that way.

Here is a screenshot of my current Hamachi configuration:

[image]

And this is the diognastics tool result:

[image]

I've already tried allowing javac.exe, javaw.exe, hamachi's executable etc from firewall but this didn't changed anything.

By the way unlike other VPNs, Hamachi doesn't changes my ip at all. Even Hamachi was on and running, my ip was different from Hamachi copies to the clipboard. Is that normal?

Comment: You should not have to put the IP. Does your hamachi IP work if you put no IP?

Comment: @RayWu No it does not work. When I try to connect to Hamachi's IP without adding it to `server.properties` file, it gives an error saying timed out.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Hamachi before, but my friend and I had this issue with our server. The issue steamed from his pc changing internal IP addresses. We had to change the IP for port forwarding and the server properties and it now works.